# Presenting Modal View Controller From Xib

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, xib, presentmodalviewcontroller

I would like to show a modal dialog from a xib. The code that shows my window is:

```
self.vcSettings = [[ViewControllerSettings alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerSettings" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];  

[self presentModalViewController:self.vcSettings animated:YES];
```

When this runs though, I get a blank screen, and not what was inside of my ViewControllerSettings.xib.  I imagine I'm showing the view incorrectly somehow.  Any advice is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I think this should be

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.vcSettings animated:YES];
```

but for some reason `self.navigationController` is nil.

**EDIT:**

Self is a UIViewController instantiated in my AppDelegate like so:

```
UIViewController* viewMain = [[ViewController_iPhone alloc]     initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.window.rootViewController = viewMain;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: How about switching the method to 

[self presentViewController:self.vcSettings animated:YES completion: ^ {
NSLog(@"%@", self.presentedViewController);
}];

What prints on the console? Is the self.presentedViewController object nil?

Comment: Make sure that the viewcontroller's `view` outlet is connected to the root view in its xib.

Comment: @Vladim, thanks, the view is connected in the root view xib

Comment: @Jacob, that line gives me a sigabrt in main if i run it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create a `UINavigationController`, set it's root view to the XIB controller that you  want to present *(in your case `vcSettings`)*, then present the `UINavigationController`

```
self.vcSettings =  [[ViewControllerSettings alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerSettings" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vcSettings];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```